# Python code isnt working the way I want it to work

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a puzzle solver for a game I play, I have everything working seamlessly well but when I run it in game it doesn't work. The game creates orange squares the appear and then quickly disappear and my goal is to click on them when they appear. The color and everything is correct but no click is made. However when I go to the Image to see if what im screenshotting is appearing correctly it starts spam clicking on the orange boxes in the Image. So I'm puzzled, what do I do to fix this issue?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

#Define the lower and upper bounds of the orange color in RGB color space
lower_orange = np.array([255, 162, 0])
    upper_orange = np.array([255, 162, 15])

while True:
    # Take a screenshot of the screen
    image = pyautogui.screenshot()
    image = np.array(image)

# Convert the image to HSV color space
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Create a mask by thresholding the image to only include pixels in the orange color range
orange_mask = cv2.inRange(rgb_image, lower_orange, upper_orange)

# Find all the contours in the mask
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(orange_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Iterate over the contours and draw a rectangle around each one
for contour in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Calculate the center of the contour
    cx = x + w // 2
    cy = y + h // 2

    # Click the center of the contour
    pyautogui.click(cx, cy)

# Show the image
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop that just takes screenshots.  None of the code that does anything with the screenshots is inside that loop, and therefore never even gets executed.

Comment: How would you recommend I fix this then? Im a little lost

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. learn the basics of the python debugger. observe your code.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem with your code is that you have a While loop that only takes a screenshot and converts it into a Numpy array. The rest of your code needs to be indented to be apart of the loop.
Here is the fixed code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

#Define the lower and upper bounds of the orange color in RGB color space
lower_orange = np.array([255, 162, 0])
    upper_orange = np.array([255, 162, 15])

while True:
    # Take a screenshot of the screen
    image = pyautogui.screenshot()
    image = np.array(image)

    # Convert the image to HSV color space
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    # Create a mask by thresholding the image to only include pixels in the orange color range
    orange_mask = cv2.inRange(rgb_image, lower_orange, upper_orange)

    # Find all the contours in the mask
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(orange_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    # Iterate over the contours and draw a rectangle around each one
    for contour in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
        # Calculate the center of the contour
        cx = x + w // 2
        cy = y + h // 2

        # Click the center of the contour
        pyautogui.click(cx, cy)
    # Show the image
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: I understand the changes but it still doesn't work.... I think it might have something to do with changing to an HSV and then back to RGB. Am I correct in assuming this or does this not have a problem?